# Could someone explain nVidia GPU architecture to me?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am just getting into GPU programming for some of my simulation work, and I've been following this tutorial:

http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/208401741

However, I'm getting the terminology confused and visiting nVidia's documentation is confusing me further.

These terms: streaming multiprocessor, threads, warps, blocks, grid, occupancy, shaders

are overwhelming me a little bit.

This is my very rough understanding:

A GPU is split into multiprocessors (maybe like 2 of them).  Each multiprocessor is split into warps, which are split into blocks, which are split into threads.  I don't know... I wish I had a diagram.  Could someone help me out?

**EDIT**: Let me explain why I'm asking this.  Suppose I'm trying to figure out what a "warp" is.  I Google "CUDA warp".  The first thing that comes up is http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_WarpsAndOccupancy.pdf.  So I scroll down and it says:

> A grid is composed of blocks 
>   which are completely 
>   independent

Okay, I get that.

> A block is composed of threads 
>   which can communicate within 
>   their own block

Okay...

> 32 threads form a warp

Now I'm lost.  32 threads form a warp?  Do all threads have to be in the same block?  Why have we arbitrarily labeled 32 threads a "warp"?  Can I call 12 threads a "satchel"?  So if a block can hold 20 threads, does that mean I need 2 blocks to contain a warp?  You can see where my confusion is coming from.  Everything I look-up depends on knowing other terms, so it's kind of like trying to learn a language by reading the dictionary — it's all circular.

Comment: What's with the close requests?  How can I modify this to prevent it from getting closed?

Comment: I don't know if your question should be closed or not, but why not try reading the CUDA docs (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)? It explains everything you're asking. It makes it seem like you haven't done much research prior to asking. Also, the Dr. Dobbs article was a good resource, but it's a bit dated now

Comment: These things get dated so fast... I think I found that from someone else's Stack Overflow question.

Comment: well, it is 5 years old now... IIRC it was written targetting compute capability 1.x. That means it has missed Fermi (2.x) and (the current) kepler architectures (3.x) completely, so some of the details aren't true anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I'm programming for a 3.5 CC so I'd like to be as current as possible.  Thanks for the programming guide link.  I'm reading that now.

Answer (score 6):

Explaining something like CUDA or a GPU architecture in the SO single question/answer format is not really feasible.  Questions that call for long discourses frequently get closed.

The challenges you face are understandable.  Sometimes you need a more orderly introduction to a topic than what you would get just by googling terms.

NVIDIA has various resources available:

- [reference docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html)
- [webinar training](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars)
- [developer support](https://developer.nvidia.com/user/register)
- [GTC on-demand](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php)

To name a few.  Let me suggest that you start by taking the introductory and advanced webinars.  If you intend to do much GPU coding, it will be about 2 hours well spent:

GPU Computing using CUDA C – An Introduction (2010)
An introduction to the basics of GPU computing using CUDA C. Concepts will be illustrated with walkthroughs of code samples. No prior GPU Computing experience required

GPU Computing using CUDA C – Advanced 1 (2010)
First level optimization techniques such as global memory optimization, and processor utilization. Concepts will be illustrated using real code examples

The fact that these are 3 years old won't matter for the questions you have.  And you certainly welcome to browse the webinars for newer versions - there are plenty.